# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection - API

Tags: javascript, api

I'm trying to extract data from an API, but I'm getting an unsuccessful exit when I add updatedSince: `\ "2020-01-01T00: 00: 00-0300 \"`

Without this parameter the array is returned, but it doesn't have the data I want

**index.js**

```
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
require('isomorphic-fetch');

fetch('https://www.bluesight.io/graphql', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
               'Bluesight-API-Token': 'api-token-here'},
    body: JSON.stringify({"query": "{squads {name cards(includedOnKanban: true, closed: false, archived: false, cancelled: false, updatedSince: \"2020-01-01T00:00:00-0300\") {identifier title description status priority assignees { fullname email } secondaryLabel primaryLabels}}}"}),})           

.then(function(response) {

    if (response.status >= 400) {

        return Promise.reject('Oops!').catch(err => {
            throw new Error(err);
          });

    }else{

        console.log("Method: POST\nContent-Type: application/json\nBluesight-API-Token: OK\nQuery: OK");
        response.json();

    }

    return response.text();
})

.then(response => console.log(response.data));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
PS C:\Users\Documents\Bluesight> node .\index.js
(node:12444) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Oops!
    at C:\Users\Documents\Bluesight\index.js:15:19
(node:12444) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
(node:12444) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
PS C:\Users\Documents\Bluesight> node .\index.js
(node:20236) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Oops!
    at C:\Users\Documents\Bluesight\index.js:15:19
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:20236) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
(node:20236) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**POSTMAN**

[image]

Comment: Try to chain `.catch(e=>console.log(e))` after last `.then()`

Comment: .then(response => console.log(response.data)).catch(e=>console.log(e)); ?

Comment: Yes, see if that helps

Comment: The error no longer appears, but does not connect with the API, the strange thing is that using POSTMAN this query execute

Comment: returned the message Oops!

Comment: at C:\Users\Documents\Bluesight\\index.js:15:19
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> node:12444) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch().
>   Above error, clearly says that you should handle promise rejection as you are throwing error

When status code is 400 or more than this code is

```
Promise.reject('Oops!').catch(err => {
            throw new Error(err);
          })
```

being executed. The above code will reject promise that should be handled in a promise chain. So adding catch as shown below in promise chain will not throw the error

```
.then(response => console.log(response.data)).catch((err)=>{
   //handle error here
 })
```

To understand it better check this REPL
https://repl.it/@sandeepp2016/HugeAvariciousLearning
Execute it first and then remove the comment and execute again, you would see the difference

Also, this code you are using has a syntax error so correct it.

```
JSON.stringify({"query": "{squads {name cards(includedOnKanban: true, closed: false, archived: false, cancelled: false, updatedSince: \"2020-01-01T00:00:00-0300\") {identifier title description status priority assignees { fullname email } secondaryLabel primaryLabels}}}"})
```

I have created one more Repl check that out.Replace actual API key and then it should work:

https://repl.it/@sandeepp2016/TrainedFinancialLaboratory

Comment: FetchError: invalid json response body at https://www.bluesight.io/graphql reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: I received the exit above

Comment: @LuisHenrique, My bad, I forgot to mention I did not correct the code. Now I did check if it works.

Comment: I execute code with new syntax is returned HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: that's probably the incorrect syntax for graphql query. As I have not worked with graphql so  I am not sure where it is incorrect. I just pointed that in your code  Json.stringify() is having a syntax problem.

Comment: I extract information https://portal.bluesight.io/api.html#available-queries